# Attempt to invoke ScrollView.removeAllViews() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I am making a simple reminder app.

The problem occurs when i close the second activity which adds a new task by using SharedPreferences and before this action there were no any task (count_of_tasks = 0).

Exception says findViewById(R.id.scroll_view) returns null :

```
ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
```

but the previous code line does not return null :

```
LinearLayout parent_layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
```

Why ?

If i restart the app, layout makes with no trouble.

Error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.memorytasks/com.example.memorytasks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4014)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4046)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.memorytasks.MainActivity.loadTasks(MainActivity.java:52)
        at com.example.memorytasks.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7572)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4046) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume () {

        super.onResume();

        loadTasks();
    }
    private void loadTasks () {

        LinearLayout parent_layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        LinearLayout tasks_layout = findViewById(R.id.tasks_layout);

        SharedPreferences sPref = getSharedPreferences("tasks", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int count_of_tasks = sPref.getInt("count_of_tasks", 0);

        parent_layout.removeAllViews();
        scrollView.removeAllViews();
        tasks_layout.removeAllViews();

        if (count_of_tasks > 0) {
            parent_layout.addView(scrollView);
            scrollView.addView(tasks_layout);
            for (int i = count_of_tasks; i > 0; i--) {
                /** Task name */
                {
                    TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    t.setId(i);
                    t.setText(sPref.getString("taskName" + i,""));
                    t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,32);
                    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50,56,142,60));
                    t.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20,10,20,10);
                    t.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tasks_layout.addView(t);
                }
                /** Extra information */
                {
                    TextView t = new TextView(this);
                    t.setId((i + 1) * i);

                    String task = sPref.getString("task" + i,"");
                    if (task.equals("")) {
                        task += "\n\n";
                    }
                    task += sPref.getString("date" + i,"");

                    t.setText(task);
                    t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,20);
                    t.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(20,56,142,60));
                    t.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20,-10,20,10);
                    t.setLayoutParams(params);
                    tasks_layout.addView(t);
                }}}
        else {
            TextView task1 = new TextView(this);
            task1.setId(R.id.task1);
            task1.setText("Здесь пока ничего нет.");
            task1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,32);
            task1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            task1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            parent_layout.addView(task1);
        }
    }
    public void fabOnClick (View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewTaskActivity.class));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
            getSharedPreferences("tasks", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
            onResume();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#388E3C"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Memory Tasks" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="fabOnClick"
        app:backgroundTint="#205020"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

context_main.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tasks_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i solved the problem by moving setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) from onCreate() to onResume().

Comment: But why there is no error with parent_layout?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if your `count_of_tasks` is 0, then the ScrollView is removed from the content view and never put back, so the next `findViewById` call is unable to find it.  You should move that `findViewById` call to your onCreate method and store it as a member variable, similar to what you did for `fab`.

This is why moving `setContentView` to onResume seemed to fix it - it would put it back each time.  Storing it will allow you to keep your `setContentView` call in onCreate.